# UITableViewCell visually has correct data on iPhone app screen, but when it's button is pressed the data that NSLogs is different

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have programmatically created a `UITableView` and I have also programmatically created UIButtons to be included with every `cell` / `row`. I have set these buttons so that if they are tapped, their specific cell's data will `NSLog` to the console.

The `UITableView` has 2 `sections`. Originally, all of the cells are placed in the 2nd section, but if I find a particular string(a person's name), then that cell is moved to the 1st section.

Each cell has a `textLabel` and a `detailTextLabel`. So far all of the cells work fine except for one.

Whenever I press a cell's button, it is supposed to `NSLog` the `detailTextLabel` property of the cell.

Here's the problem. For some reason, all of the buttons work fine except for the very first one. The first cell visually shows the correct `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` on the app screen. The `textLabel` value is "Mom" and the `detailTextLabel` value is "momusername", so when I press this cell's button it should be NSLogging "momusername".

For some reason though, it `NSLogs` the `detailTextLabel` of the first cell in the second section with a value of "dadusername", even though it visually shows the correct `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` on the app screen.

What's even weirder, is if I change everything so that it is supposed to NSLog the `textLabels`, the first cell will STILL `NSlog` the detailTextLabel.

I don't understand how the cell can visually show a textLabel of "mom" and a detailTextLabel of "momusername", but then `NSLog` completely different values.

It only wants to NSLog the `detailTextLabel` of the first cell in the 2nd section.

Is it possible that the cell is being reused when it shouldn't be, or that something is wrong with "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier"?

Below is my entire View Controller from where I first start setting up the `UITableView`. The only thing missing is that at the very beginning of `viewDidLoad` I am using these 2 statements: `self.tableView.dataSource = self;` and  `self.cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];`

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2 ;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"SECTION 0 LOG: %@", self.potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray);


    if(section == 0)

        return [self.potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray count];
    if(section == 1)

        return [self.potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray count];

    else return 0;


}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SettingsCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];

    cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


    if (indexPath.section == 0) {


        NSString *firstNameForTableView = [self.potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *userNameForTableView = [self.potentiaFriendsUsernameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



        UIImage *addUserButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal-g"];
        UIImage *addUserButtonImageHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal"];


        _addUserButton.frame = CGRectMake(237, -10, 64, 64);

        [_addUserButton setImage:addUserButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_addUserButton setImage:addUserButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [_addUserButton setImage:addUserButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        [_addUserButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        _addUserButton.tag = indexPath.row;

        [cell.textLabel setText:firstNameForTableView];

        [cell.detailTextLabel setText:userNameForTableView];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:_addUserButton];

    } else {


        NSString *firstNameForTableView2 = [self.potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *userNameForTableView2 = [self.potentiaFriendsPhoneNumberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        UIImage *addFriendButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal-G"];
        UIImage *addFriendButtonImageHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal"];

        UIButton *addFriendButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];

        addFriendButton.frame = CGRectMake(237, -10, 64, 64);

        [addFriendButton setImage:addFriendButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [addFriendButton setImage:addFriendButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [addFriendButton setImage:addFriendButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        [addFriendButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchUpInsideForNonUsers:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        addFriendButton.tag = indexPath.row;

        [cell.textLabel setText:firstNameForTableView2];

        [cell.detailTextLabel setText:userNameForTableView2];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:addFriendButton];

    }

    return cell;

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if(section == 0)
        return @"Friends Using This App";
    if(section == 1)
        return @"Send to Contact";

    else return @"nil";

}


- (void)handleTouchUpInside:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;

    UIButton *cellButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:cellButton.tag inSection:0];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
    cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(sender.state == 5) {

    [_usersToAddToFriendsList addObject:cell.textLabel.text];

    } else {

        [_usersToAddToFriendsList removeObject:cell.textLabel.text];

    }


}


- (void)handleTouchUpInsideForNonUsers:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;


    UIButton *cellButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:cellButton.tag inSection:1];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
    cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(sender.state == 5) {

        //This add's the username to the array.

        [_usersToInviteToApp addObject:cell.detailTextLabel.text];

    } else {

        [_usersToInviteToApp removeObject:cell.detailTextLabel.text];

    }    
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use next method on `UITableViewDelegate` :

```
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

and add delegate like:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: where should I add "tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:" in my code? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Some like you add `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code it may help you
@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
UITableView *menuTableView;
NSMutableArray *potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray,*potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
menuTableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 404) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
menuTableView.delegate=self;
menuTableView.dataSource=self;
menuTableView.separatorColor=[UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:menuTableView];
potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // info array for section 0
potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // info array for section 1

/* static info for testing starts here */

NSArray * names=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d", nil];
    NSArray * subNames=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"aa",@"ab",@"ac",@"ad", nil];
for (int i=0; i<names.count; i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setObject:names[i] forKey:@"title"];
    [dict setObject:subNames[i] forKey:@"subtitle"];
    [potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray addObject:dict];
}
/* static info for testing ends here */
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 2 ;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {  
if(section == 0)
    return [potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray count]; // initially this will be zero
else if(section == 1)
    return [potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray count]; // shows with static content

else return 0;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}

if (indexPath.section == 0) {



    UIImage *addUserButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal-g"];
    UIImage *addUserButtonImageHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal"];

    UIButton *_addUserButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 _addUserButton.frame = CGRectMake(237, -10, 64, 64);

    [_addUserButton setImage:addUserButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_addUserButton setImage:addUserButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_addUserButton setImage:addUserButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [_addUserButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [_addUserButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    _addUserButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    [cell.textLabel setText:[[potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]];

    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[[potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"subtitle"]];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:_addUserButton];

  } 
else
 { 
    UIImage *addFriendButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal-G"];
    UIImage *addFriendButtonImageHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal"];

    UIButton *addFriendButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    addFriendButton.frame = CGRectMake(237, -10, 64, 64);
    [addFriendButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [addFriendButton setImage:addFriendButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [addFriendButton setImage:addFriendButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [addFriendButton setImage:addFriendButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [addFriendButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouchUpInsideForNonUsers:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    addFriendButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    [cell.textLabel setText:[[potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]];

    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[[potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:addFriendButton];

}

return cell;

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if(section == 0)
    return @"Friends Using This App";
if(section == 1)
    return @"Send to Contact";

else return @"nil";

}


- (void)handleTouchUpInside:(UIButton *)sender {

NSLog(@"%@",[potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag]);
[menuTableView reloadData];
}


- (void)handleTouchUpInsideForNonUsers:(UIButton *)sender {


[potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray addObject:potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray[sender.tag]];
[potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray removeObjectAtIndex:sender.tag];
[menuTableView reloadData];

}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.section==0) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[potentiaFriendsInParseFirstNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [UITableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath%3a)

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
}
```

Before this you have to set delegate to self as

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```